# git tracked a directory and ignored the subdirectories

Tags: git, gitignore

The contents of my folder are:

```
.cpanel/
.git/
.trash/
.vim/
bin/
etc/
laravel/
logs/
mail/
perl5/
php/
public_html/
repo.git/
ssl/
```

Here is my .gitignore file

```
.*
~/.gitignore
*.git/
access-logs/
etc/
logs/
mail/
php/
ssl/
tmp/
trash/
vendor/
error_log
\.bak\.
```

When I clone from my git repository, the laravel folder in my local machine shows as:

**The contents of `ls -la laravel` from local machine**

```
total 8
drwxrwxr-x 2 mfissehaye mfissehaye 4096 ኦክተ 22 05:34 .
drwxrwxr-x 5 mfissehaye mfissehaye 4096 ኦክተ 22 05:34 ..
```

**The contents of `ls -la laravel` from server**

```
total 124
drwxr-xr-x  5 malameng malameng  4096 2015-10-22 02:52 .
drwxr-xr-x 18 malameng nobody    4096 2015-10-22 03:04 ..
drwxr-xr-x 13 malameng malameng  4096 2015-03-20 05:54 app
-rw-r--r--  1 malameng malameng  2452 2015-03-17 09:44 artisan
drwxr-xr-x  2 malameng malameng  4096 2015-03-20 05:55 bootstrap
-rw-r--r--  1 malameng malameng   798 2015-03-17 09:44 composer.json
-rw-r--r--  1 malameng malameng 68065 2015-03-17 09:44 composer.lock
-rw-r--r--  1 malameng malameng   146 2015-03-17 09:44 CONTRIBUTING.md
-rw-r--r--  1 malameng malameng   606 2015-10-21 09:25 error_log
-rw-r--r--  1 malameng malameng    12 2015-03-17 09:44 .gitattributes
-rw-r--r--  1 malameng malameng   100 2015-03-17 09:44 .gitignore
-rw-r--r--  1 malameng malameng   567 2015-03-17 09:44 phpunit.xml
-rw-r--r--  1 malameng malameng  2051 2015-03-17 09:44 readme.md
-rw-r--r--  1 malameng malameng   519 2015-03-17 09:44 server.php
drwxr-xr-x 24 malameng malameng  4096 2015-03-20 05:54 vendor
```

**Something I did before pushing my changes to the repo**
The laravel folder had its own .git folder. I removed that. I didn't wanna deal with submodule and stuff.

Comment: Please provide the output of following: `ls -la laravel`.

Comment: what is the content of .gitignore ? Do you commit the laravel content ?

Comment: The output you provided is from your server? Whereas output from local machine shows empty folder?

Comment: @AndrejsCainikovs that's right

Comment: `it shows the laravel/ folder but not its contents` Put what you see in the question please, don't describe problems - show them. @Ôrel that's in the question.

Comment: @AD7six I meant to say the laravel folder in my local machine is empty. So basically it shows nothing.

Comment: **Put what you see in the question please, don't describe problems - show them**

Comment: Sorry for  the lack of precision you have a `.gitignore` into laravel, what is its content. Do you have a global gitignore ?

Comment: @Ôrel I don't have a global .gitignore

Comment: It looks like you have a git repo inside your git repo.

Comment: `The laravel folder had its own .git folder. I removed that.` You're on a path to pain - I recommend to read about [how to use composer](https://getcomposer.org/doc/00-intro.md).

Comment: @AD7six thanks. That makes sense. But why would this happen at all.

Comment: The contents of `/laravel` are not _in_ your git repo at all, hence when you clone it these untracked files are not there to be found, at all. At a guess, in the absence of any details.

Comment: @AD7six can I add them now? Because my `git status` command doesn't show them as untracked

Comment: **You're on a path to pain - I recommend to read about how to use composer.**. Yes you can, but you probably shouldn't, good luck. (I don't really see how "untracked files in one checkout don't magically appear when I clone the repo to another location is confusing - or a question worth upvoting btw).

Comment: That's why I guessed, there might be something wrong with the .gitignore file

Comment: What happen if you try to commit a file from the directory `.gitignore` for example ?

Comment: Found this helpful. Thanks to @AD7six [the third bullet in composer docs](https://getcomposer.org/doc/faqs/should-i-commit-the-dependencies-in-my-vendor-directory.md)